# My prefix is the ruler of all our lives

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix is the ruler of all our lives.
>
> My suffix hints us thrashing knives.
>
> My infix before the fire was a cane.
>
> My whole pretends that it's insane.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Great riddle!

You are

> CASHEW

> My prefix is the ruler of all our lives.

> CASH. Cash plays an integral role in our day to day lives.

> My suffix hints us thrashing knives.

> HEW. Thrashing knives could mean chopping at an object, since knives are made to chop. Hew means precisely this.

> My infix before the fire was a cane.

> ASH. Ash is what is the remains from plant material being burnt. This line points at Ash before being (in contact with) the fire was a cane.

> My whole pretends that it's insane

> CASHEW is often wrongly classified as a nut and so can be said to 'pretend to be one' and nuts can mean crazy so it pretends to be crazy.

Comment: The first clue could also be rot13(P, sbe pneoba, hcba juvpu nyy xabja yvsrsbezf ner onfrq.)